# Adding to b2world, external box2d bodies from external classes

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, objective-c++

using obj-c box2d and cocos2d, im attempting to create my box2d objects in a separate Class, for convenience sake and to group objects together.
Basically, I have two Classes:

Constructor - The Box2d world is loaded and the OpenGL draw methods exist here
Gate - A Class that has multiple objects, two sprites, a Door sprite and a Switch sprite with their own bounding boxes etc.

At the moment I have this:

```
@interface Gate : CCNode {
@private
    //Door Gadget:
    b2Body *body_door;
    b2BodyDef def_door;
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    CGRect boundingBox_door;
    CCSprite *sprite_door;

}
-(void)createGate:(CGPoint)gateLoc:(CGPoint)switchLoc;
@property (assign) CGRect boundingBox_door;
@property (assign) CCSprite *sprite_door;
@property (assign) b2Body *body_door;
@property (assign) b2BodyDef def_door;
@property (assign) b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;


@end


@implementation Gate

-(void) createGate:(CGPoint)doorLoc:(CGPoint)switchLoc{
//please note that these variables are global and synthesized inside the header file

    sprite_door = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"eggBIG.png"];
    sprite_door.position = gateLoc;

    //Gadget 1 - Door Physics Body
    def_door.type = b2_dynamicBody;                 
    def_door.position.Set(gateLoc.x/PTM_RATIO,gateLoc.y/PTM_RATIO);
    def_door.userData = sprite_door;                

    b2PolygonShape dynamic_block1;              
    dynamic_block1.SetAsBox(15.0f/PTM_RATIO, 15.0f/PTM_RATIO);
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamic_block1;
    fixtureDef.density = 3.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 1.0f;

}
```

Constructor Class .mm -

```
@implementation Constructor
-(id) init{
//Create Gate
        Gate *gate = [[Gate alloc]init];
        [gate createGate:ccp(300,300) :ccp(400,400)];
        [self addChild:gate.sprite_door];
        b2BodyDef def_door = gate.def_door;
        gate.body_door = world->CreateBody(&def_door);
        b2Fixture *doorFixture;
        b2FixtureDef fixtureDef = gate.fixtureDef;
        doorFixture = gate.body_door->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
        doorFixture->SetUserData(@"sprite_door");
}
```

Because this is objective-c++, i cannot directly add properties to the variables inside C Method. For example:
doorFixture = gate.body_door->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
cannot be:
doorFixture = gate.body_door->CreateFixture(&gate.fixtureDef);

I'm not very proficient with C++, so this is a little daunting.
This is quite important for the architecture of my game, so please help :)

Comment: what's the question or problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you notice in the your `Constructor::init` method, you create `gate.body_door` using b2BodyDef `gate.def_door` and attach to it b2Fixture that is created using `gate.fixtureDef`? The only value the `Constructor` object contribute the process is the `world` object.

Look at it using this analogy:

> You are making a cake. You have the flour, eggs, sugar,
>   butter etc but you don't have the
>   baking pan; your neighbour has it. Do
>   you bring all your ingredients to your
>   neighbour house and bake the cake
>   there or do you just borrow the baking
>   pan and bake it at your house? Which
>   is the more logical option to take?

What I'm trying to convey is why do you need a method in `Constructor` class to set up the body when you can just create a method in the `Gate` class to do it? Like below:

```
@implementation Gate

-(void) createBodyInWorld:(b2World*)world andUserData:(void*)userData {
        body_door = world->CreateBody(&def_door);
        b2Fixture *doorFixture = body_door->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
        doorFixture->SetUserData(userData);
}

...

@end

@implementation Constructor
-(id) init{
//Create Gate
        Gate *gate = [[Gate alloc]init];
        [gate createGate:ccp(300,300) withSwitchLoc:ccp(400,400)];
        [gate createBodyInWorld:world andUserData:@"sprite_door"];
        [self addChild:gate.sprite_door];
}
```

See in the `createBodyInWorld:andUserData:` method you don't have to worry about accessing the properties since you can directly access the ivars.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I didn't realize I could move the world object across to another class method. I just had it in my mind that it was set in stone within the construct method. This is going to clean up my code so much! I'll implement it tomorrow and post up if I have any problems.